# Javascript SHIFT and POP on Associative Array

Tags: javascript, associative-array, shift

Using a regular array I am able to grab the image src from an array using `shift()` and `pop()`; I would like to do the same thing using an associative array to add a name and id.

Single Array

```
var products = ['product1.jpg'];
$('#products').append('<img src="' + products.shift() + '">');
```

Associative Array

```
var products = [{id:'1',name:'product 1',image:'product1.jpg'}];
$('#products').append('<img id="' + products.shift() + '" name="' + products.shift() + '" src="' + products.shift() + '">');
```

Comment: Note that "regular arrays" in JavaScript are also associative arrays. It's just that they get a bunch of additional array methods - but they're still associative arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line: `var products = [{id:'1',name:'product 1',image:'product1.jpg'}];` declares an array with a single value inside. The single value is an object with the properties `id`, `name`, and `image`. When you call `shift` on the array, the value returned will be this object.

Comment: Note that your answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I think my answer gives enough information for the OP to realise the problem himself, and stops just short of writing the code for him. I have edited it slightly.

Comment: I tried several of them and they all work, I appreciate all the help with this. Thanks everyone! For the project I am working, I was able to make slight changes. I learned enough based on Finbarr’s explanation to teach me what I had to do to make it work from a Single Array to an Associative Array. But again, they all worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're using a regular array full of objects, so shift and pop will work, but return you the object.

```
var products = [{id:'1',name:'product 1',image:'product1.jpg'}];
var prod = products.shift();
$('#products').append('<img id="' + prod.id + '" name="' + prod.name + '" src="' + prod.image + '">');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var products = [{id:'1',name:'product 1',image:'product1.jpg'}];

for(var i =0; i < products.length; i++){
  var product = products[i];
  $('#products').append('<img id="' + product.id + '" name="' + product.name + '" src="' + product.image + '">');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

shift() is going to pull the whole object out of the index, not piece by piece like in your example.

You would need to access the object by name to get what you want.

```
var products = [{id:'1',name:'product 1',image:'product1.jpg'}, {id:'2',name:'product 2',image:'product2.jpg'}];

var currentProduct = products.shift();
$('#products').append('<img id="' +  currentProduct.id + '" name="' + currentProduct.name + '" src="' + currentProduct.image + '">');
```

to loop through it

```
while(products.length>0){
    var currentProduct = products.shift();
    $('#products').append('<img id="' +  currentProduct.id + '" name="' + currentProduct.name + '" src="' + currentProduct.image + '">');
}
```

better performance loop would be one write to the DOM

```
var strOut = "";
while(products.length>0){
    var currentProduct = products.shift();
    strOut  += '<img id="' +  currentProduct.id + '" name="' + currentProduct.name + '" src="' + currentProduct.image + '">';
}
$('#products').append( strOut );
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can cache the shift, and use the object's properties:

   ```
   var products = [{id:'1',name:'product 1',image:'product1.jpg'}];
   var product  = products.shift();
   $('#products').append('<img id="' + product.id 
                        + '" name="' + product.name 
                        + '" src="'  + product.image + '">');
   ```
2. You can store the values differently, as a multi-dimensional array:

   ```
   var products = [['1','product 1','product1.jpg']];
   var product  = products.shift();
   $('#products').append('<img id="' + product.shift()
                        + '" name="' + product.shift() 
                        + '" src="'  + product.shift() + '">');
   ```